# Which NSRegularExpression was found using the | operator

Tags: ios, swift, nsregularexpression

I'm currently implementing `NSRegularExpressions` to check for patterns inside a `UITextView` string in my project.

The patterns check and operations are working as expected; for example: I'm trying to find the regular `**bold**` markdown pattern and if I find it I apply some text attributed to the range, and it works as expected.

I have though came across a problem. I don't know how to run multiple patterns at once and apply different operations for each pattern found.

In my `UITextView` delegate `textViewDidChange` or `shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange` I am running the bold pattern check `\\*{2}([\\w ]+)\\*{2}` but then I am as well running the italic pattern check `\\_{1}([\\w ]+)\\_{1}`, looping again through the `UITextView text`.

I have implemented the following custom function, that applies the passed in `regex` to the string, but I have to call this function multiple times to check for each pattern, that's why I'd love to put the pattern check into one single, then "parse" each `match`.

```
fileprivate func regularExpression(regex: NSRegularExpression, type: TypeAttributes) {
    let str = inputTextView.attributedText.string
    let results = regex.matches(in: str, range: NSRange(str.startIndex..., in: str))
    _ = results.map { self.applyAttributes(range: $0.range, type: type) }
}
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I can "merge" both patterns with the `|` operand like the following:

`private let combinedPattern = "\\*{2}([\\w ]+)\\*{2}|\\_{1}([\\w ]+)\\_{1}"`

but my problem is to know which pattern was found the `\\*{2}([\\w ]+)\\*{2}` one or the `\\_{1}([\\w ]+)\\_{1}`

Comment: you will apply this two pattern on same range you searched for or on another parts

Comment: Same range, the whole text. I can "merge" two patterns with the `|` operand, but I don't know which match is what when iterating through the `.matches`

Comment: Unrelated, but calling `map` then discarding the results makes no sense. If you simply want to iterate over a collection and apply a closure to all of its values without returning anything, use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor you’re right, I’ve implemented this based on a previous answer by Martin R. , anyway I’ll fix it when I solve this :)

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure you want to combine that into one expression. I am worried that you want to match both, even when they overlap but with `|` only one of them will be matched. Also, you should probably include all whitespace characters `\s` in your pattern, not only single spaces. Also, I am pretty sure that `_` is included in `\w` therefore you should specifically exlude it `[\\w\\s^_]`.

Comment: @Sulthan thanks for pointing that out. I’ll perform some additional tests with those regex modifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the combined pattern you have the results in different range of the match result.

If you want to access the first capture group (the bold pattern) you need to access the range at 1. When the match matches the second group you will have the first with an invalid range, so you need to check if it's valid of not this way:

```
results.forEach {
    var range = $0.range(at: 1)
    if range.location + range.length < str.count {
         self.applyAttributes(range: range, type: .bold)
    }
    range = $0.range(at: 2)
    if range.location + range.length < str.count {
        self.applyAttributes(range: range, type: .italic)
    }
}
```

After that you can extend your `TypeAttributes` enum to return the index range that is linked to your regular expression:

```
extension NSRange {
    func isValid(for string:String) -> Bool {
        return location + length < string.count
    }
}

let attributes: [TypeAttributes] = [.bold, .italic]

results.forEach { match in
    attributes.enumerated().forEach { index, attribute in
         let range = match.range(at: index+1)
         if range.isValid(for: str) {                
             self.applyAttributes(range: range, type: attribute[index]) 
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I had no idea this was possible. I’m currently not in front of my machine to test this , but as soon as I can, I’ll test it and I’ll feedback to you. It looks that this will solve my issue. Thank you!

Comment: of course! Tell me if it works! I just edited the answer to add the enum mapping to the result.

Comment: that extension really eases everything. With that I’ll be able to insert any attributes and just check them and apply changes to it. Pretty impressive. Looking forward to test this out, but I’m 100% sure it will work. Thank you so much

Comment: just to notice, the `key+1` is supposed to be `index+1`?

Comment: can you check [this](https://github.com/Ivan-Cantarino/regex_markdown).

Somehow it confuses some of the attributes

Comment: it is working with bold but with italics has some weird behavior. If you could see the linked project and have a look I’d appreciate it a lot.

Comment: it's strange, yes I'm going to take a look when I have a computer. and yes, it's index and not key, I started with a Dictionary and then changed to Array...

Comment: I've a full sampled working project there. If you have a look you'll notice the weird behavior on the italics. There I check if the deleted char is a `*` or `_` I run the default pattern, to attribute the default parameter to the word, then I run the bold and italic, so it rebuilds those lose ends. ;)

Comment: [here](https://i.imgur.com/fjxSUiA.gifv) is a gif I've recorded of the sample project

Comment: I think that the problem is that you are changing the string while looping  through the string results, and the range of the result gets outdated. Could be that the problem?

Comment: I guess it could be a problem, though I'm not quite sure how to surpass it since I need to update the attributes on the fly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171032/discussion-between-ivan-cantarino-and-davebcn87).