# Exclude pattern in NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, swift, nsregularexpression

Imagine the following sentence:

`The **quick** brown **fox** ...`

If I run the following `regex`

```
let boldPattern = "\\*{2}([\\w ]+)\\*{2}"

let boldRegex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: boldPattern)

let str = "The **quick** brown **fox** ..."

let results = regex.matches(in: str, range: NSRange(str.startIndex..., in: str))

results.forEach {
    print("$0")
}
```

I'm able to get all the words between the `**`.

I have read about negative regex, which returns every words except the ones we're trying to "avoid".

Given the above sentence, is there a way to use a negative `regex` to get words that doesn't match the `boldPattern`, so I would get `The brown ...`, avoiding the `**words**` ??

**Edit**

I'm looking for something around this pattern `((?!\\*{2}([\\w ]+)\\*{2}).*)` , something that searches for words that doesn't start with `** word **`

Comment: Actually `*` is the problem if it was any other character it will be easier. `*` itself has its meaning in regex.

Comment: @TheTiger yeah, you’re right. I’ve no idea how to solve this. Regular expressions are so tricky.

Comment: In which case your regex is working wrong?

Comment: @TheTiger it doesn’t print any error, but it doesn’t match any text. This could be a typo in the regex string.

Comment: You're printing `print("$0")` whatever you write in double quotes it will be a string so it will print hard coded `$0` every time even after it matches. It should be something like `results.forEach { (value) in
                let range = value.range
                let matchString = (str as NSString).substring(with: range) as String
                print(matchString)
            }`

Comment: @TheTiger I’m currently afk, but when I get back home I’ll try as you’ve suggested and I’ll feedback ;)

Comment: Hey, Did you solve your issue? I am doing R&D on regex since last night :|

Comment: @TheTiger it’s more less solved. I’ve another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50326149/3636256) with a sample project I’ve attached. Have a look we talk there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `NSRegularExpression`'s `stringByReplacingMatches` method.

Example:

```
let boldPattern = "\\*{2}([\\w ]+)\\*{2}"
let boldRegex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: boldPattern)
let str = "The **quick** brown **fox** ..."

let unmatchedString = boldRegex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.count), withTemplate: "")
print(unmatchedString)
// prints: The  brown  ...
```

Comment: That may help me solving my issue for sure, though I may encounter a problem later. I think I malformed my question. Let's say I have a bold text with the `**tag**` , later I delete a single `*` char, so it doesn't match the bold pattern. What I'm trying to do is to apply the default text style , taking off the bold attributes, thus my need to iterate through the string and "avoid" those bold patterns, so I wouldn't apply the default attributes to it.
Even though, your answer, answers my question, so I'll accept it as correct.